# Limiting the Number of Checked Checkboxes with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, ember.js

I am using Twitter Bootstrap to to create a list of checkboxes. Below is my template (written in Emblem):

```
.form-group
  .checkbox
     label
       input type="checkbox" Position
  .checkbox
     label
       input type="checkbox" LFP
  .checkbox
     label
       input type="checkbox" Position &middot; LFP 1st PC
  / more...
```

I want to limit the number of boxes that can be checked at once.  When at the limit, unchecked boxes should be grayed out or something similar. If it matters, I am doing this in the context of EmberJS and am attaching Ember actions to the checkboxes. How do I set a limit?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a view that has `disabledBinding` on some model attribute and can catch `change` or `click` events (http://emberjs.com/guides/views/handling-events/) and send event to controller. I suppose your checkboxes values are mapped to model in controller, so it is possible to iterate over this model and set attribute that `disabledBinding` is connected to.

Custom view is nessessary for catching events. Disabling is build in - just provide binding to control it

Comment: Actually events are not that nessessary, you can just use `observes` function in controller on property that is mapped to checkbox values (http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Function.html#method_observes)

Comment: Thanks Yury, I didn't create a view but was able to solve this by binding `disabled` to properties on objects stored in a controller property, and using `observes` like you suggest. If you edit your answer to reflect your comment and provide a short code example I will accept it.